# Name of the song in Girls Und Panzer

Tags: music, girls-und-panzer

In certain episode of Girls Und Panzer, there is a song with foreign language (more likely Russian because during that time protagonists team battle against with Soviet team). What is the name of that song?

Comment: Do you mean [this song](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=epclAbW1APk&t=45)? Ifo so this is a old Russian wartime song called ["Katyusha"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katyusha_(song))

Comment: just a side note that all team are from Japanese despite having a foreign theme, so there's no Soviet team. They're Pravda. And the school is located in Aomori Prefecture, and most of the student are Japanese. (only one known Russian, Klara)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a old Russian wartime song called "[Katyusha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katyusha_%28song%29)."

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=epclAbW1APk&t=45